# Поиск с помощью гема ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

Решил организовать поиск новостей по ключевым словам, да можно написать поиск вручную, но нашел универсальное решение, гем ransack нашел документацию подключил и вроде как запустил, но как я вижу в моем приложении он не подключен, возможно что то сделал не так, поиск в гугле не дал решения. Рельсы 4,2,1

контроллер

```
    @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
    @article = @q.result(distinct: true)
@articles = Article.published.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6)
```

вьюха

```
 .container-fluid
  .row
    -#.col-md-1
    .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
      .panel.panel-info{style:"font-size: 14px;"}
        .panel-heading
          %i
            .path
              Новости
        .panel-body
          - unless @articles.present?
            .row
              .col-md-12
                %center
                  %h2
                    Данный раздел находится в наполнении.

          - else
            .col-md-12
              .pull-right
                %form.form-inline
                  .form-group
                    -#= form_tag(request.path, method: "get", class: "form-horizontal") do
                    = search_form_for @q  do | f |
                      = f.label :name_cont, 'Поиск по новостям'
                      %br
                      = f.text_field :name_cont
                      = f.submit "Поиск"
                      -#= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Поиск по новостям", class: "form-control"
            %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed
            - @articles.each do |article|
              .my_panel
                .my_panel-heading
                  .row
                    .col-md-2{style:'font-size: 13px;'}
                      .pull-left
                        %i.fa-fw.fa.fa-calendar
                        = I18n. l article.created_at, format: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%m'
```

Пробовал вместо метода ransack использовать search, но не заработал.

```
Started GET "/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bname_cont%5D=%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81&commit=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-04 10:31:53 +0300
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"Барс"}, "commit"=>"Поиск"}
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."show" = 't'  ORDER BY "articles"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0
```

По консоли сервера видно, что он не обращается к ransack, а загружает @articles

Comment: Неудивительно. Вы результаты поиска кладёте в `@article` и успешно о них забываете во всех остальных местах.

Comment: Да, был невнимательным, спасибо все заработало

Comment: d-side, а можно задать вопросик, если не затруднит, в общем а если например делать поиск глобальный обращаясь ко всем моделям и можно ли это реализовать с ransack либо что-то другое можно использовать?

Comment: Есть соображения. [**Но давайте лучше в чате**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41316/ruby-on-rails--).